# Jquery is undefined error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have  **MVC2** application and I am trying to automatically resize my `Textareafor` using Jquery

**Code:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/jquery.autoresize.js">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#target").autoResize();
    });
</script>

  <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.QDetail, new { @id="target" }) %>
```

and in my `Content Folder` I only have **query.autoresize.js**

On compiling it gives me `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined` error

What am I missing ?

Thank you All

Comment: You should include jquery.js file before to jquery.autoresize.js. jquery.autoresize.js has dependecy on jQuery

Answer (score 2):

first add jquery file then add your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>// add jQuery
 //^^^^add jquery file

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/jquery.autoresize.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#target").autoResize();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

above your autosize.js add:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/jquery.autoresize.js"></script>
//add here script start tag
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#target").autoResize();
    });
</script>
```

and if you are using offline app then download library and add physical path like you added `jquery.autoresize.js`